# Pagination using startAt() when ordering by child

Tags: javascript, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to just retrieve a list of records, sorted by one of the fields in each record, and I would like to be able to retrieve the data in pages.

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt), the `reference.startAt()` method has an optional 2nd parameter, which is:

`The child key to start at. This argument is only allowed if ordering by child, value, or priority.`

First off, here is the data:

```
{
  "products" : {
    "-KlsqFgVWwUrA-j0VsZS" : {
      "name" : "Product 4",
      "price" : 666
    },
    "-Klst-cLSckuwAuNAJF8" : {
      "name" : "Product 1",
      "price" : 100
    },
    "-Klst7IINdt8YeMmauRz" : {
      "name" : "Product 2",
      "price" : 50
    },
    "-Klst9KfM2QWp8kXrOlR" : {
      "name" : "Product 6",
      "price" : 30
    },
    "-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6" : {
      "name" : "Product 5",
      "price" : 99
    },
    "-KlstDR5cCayGH0XKtZ0" : {
      "name" : "Product 3",
      "price" : 500
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code which is able to retrieve Page 1 (lowest priced item + 2nd lowest priced + 3rd lowest priced):

*(I am using Firebase JS SDK 4.1.1)*

```
'use strict';
var firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "your-api-key",
    authDomain: "your-firebase-domain",
    databaseURL: "https://your-db.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "your-project",
    storageBucket: "your-bucket.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "your-sender-id"
})

firebase.database().ref('products')
.orderByChild('price')
.limitToFirst(3)
.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key;
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(key + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

Output:

TJ:database tjwoon$ node test.js

```
-Klst9KfM2QWp8kXrOlR: {"name":"Product 6","price":30}
-Klst7IINdt8YeMmauRz: {"name":"Product 2","price":50}
-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6: {"name":"Product 5","price":99}
```

Page 2 should be the 3rd lowest, 4th lowest, and 5th lowest priced products, which means my code need one additional line:

```
firebase.database().ref('products')
.orderByChild('price')
.startAt(null, '-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6')
.limitToFirst(3)
.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key;
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(key + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

Output:

```
TJ:database tjwoon$ node test.js
-Klst9KfM2QWp8kXrOlR: {"name":"Product 6","price":30}
-Klst7IINdt8YeMmauRz: {"name":"Product 2","price":50}
-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6: {"name":"Product 5","price":99}
```

The problem is that it is returning Page 1 again. If the documentation is correct, the results should start at the record with key `-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6`.

I have tried adding an `.indexOn` rule for the price field, but the results remained identical.

If I remove the `orderByChild()` line, then the results do start from the given key, but of course the sorting is incorrect, plus it behaves contrary to the documentation...

I found these other Stack Overflow posts which describe the same problem:

- [Firebase orderByChild with startAt()'s second argument w/ pagination not odering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995881/firebase-orderbychild-with-startats-second-argument-w-pagination-not-odering)
- *(see comment below. I don't have enough reputation to include the link here)*

However there are no answers to those questions and quite few responses. There are no issues in the Github repository which match the search term `startat`.

Is anyone else facing the same issue? This problem makes it impossible to retrieve a sorted list in a paginated manner...

Comment: 2nd StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779947/firebase-querying-when-combining-orderbychild-startat-and-limittofirst?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there!

The problem is in how you call `startAt` for the second page:

```
.startAt(null, '-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6')
```

To get the correct results you need to pass in both the price and the key of the so-called anchor item:

```
.startAt(99, '-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6')
```

With that Firebase will find all items with `price` `99` and then return items starting at key `'-KlstB51ap1L2tcK8cL6'`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the 1st parameter is the "main" startAt criteria, with the 2nd parameter serving as a kind of disambiguation value in case multiple children have the same value. This is awesome, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd like to know how to use this feature via REST. If anyone can help, this is what I ask at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909798/how-use-firebase-startat-method-with-value-and-key-in-rest-request